Does there exist an orthonomormal basis of $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$
Define $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$={ $f:[-\pi,\pi] \to \Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, and $f$ is square integrable }, where I want to consider real and complex value measurable functions separetely.I know that there exist an orthonormal set $H$={$1,cos(nx), sin(nx): n\in \Bbb N$ }. I want to use stone weierstrass approximation( in real and complex version) to prove that $\Bbb R$ span $H$ and $\Bbb C$ span $H$ is dense in $L^2$( for $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ respectively) But I have trouble for the separate points part. In other words, given $ -\pi\le x\lt y\le \pi$. I want to find an element $f,g$ in $\Bbb R$ span $H$,and in $\Bbb C$ span $H$, such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$ and $g(x)\neq g(y)$ The most important problem is for $x=\pi$ and $y=-\pi$, since H is 2$\pi$ periodic, so is the elements in $\Bbb R$ span $H$,and in $\Bbb C$ span $H$.  I think it is impossible to find such $f$ and $g$. However, my professor says that it is possible, can someone help me, thanks

Apply Stone-Weierstrass on the circle $T$. $-\pi$ and $\pi$ correspond to the same point on the circle.

@geetha290krm so what you say is that we can first consider the space $L^2(T)$ and since lebesgue $L^2$ space is an equivalence class space ( almost everywhere) so we get it is orthonomal basis.
